# dockedItems - text from Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have Tree panel.

**everything works!;**

```
Ext.define('My.Tree', {
    extend:'Ext.tree.Panel',
    id: 'DriveTree',
    store: storeTree,


    ChooseButtonText: 'ChooseFolder',
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
         items: [{
           text: 'BUTTON TEXT', //  this.ChooseButtonText
           id:'connectButton',

                   handler: function(){

                              alert(this.ChooseButtonText);

                         }
         }, 

         ]
    }],


});



Ext.onReady(function(){
var tree =Ext.create('My.Tree', {});
});
```

But text of  dockedItems want to be from  Panel. something like this:

```
text:this.ChooseButtonText
```

**each dockedItems have listener -  handler: function(){}. How can I see that variables in this function too?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in initComponent:

```
Ext.define('My.Tree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    id: 'DriveTree',
    store: storeTree,

    ChooseButtonText: 'ChooseFolder',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.dockedItems = [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: this.ChooseButtonText,
                scope: this,
                handler: this.onConnectButtonClick
            }]
        }];
        this.callParent();
    },

    onConnectButtonClick: function() {
        console.log('Do something');
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'insert'

Comment: each dockedItems have listener -  handler: function(){}. How can I see that variables in this function too?